# How to properly install multicols.sty on a WinEdt system?

Tags: packages, multicol

I've downloaded the `multicols.sty` file and need to install it so that it works on my copy of WinEdt 7, I just need to figure out which directory the file should go into, seeking assistance with working that out.

Comment: installation of the new packages has nothing with editor (winedt 7). correct way to install them in miktex is by miktex's wizard "update miktex", which is part of its installation. or use option "install missing packages on-the-fly".

Comment: no. multicol is part of the "required" core latex distribution. If you have been given a latex that does not include `multicol.sty` (no s) then complain to the person distributing the broken copy of latex.